# ASM component is not displaying properly

Tags: java, sap-commerce-cloud, add-on, hybris-data-hub

Assisted Service Mode component is not working properly.
It could be frontend problem. How can I solve?

This is how it looks on my screen:

[image]

This is what I expect:

[image]

Comment: I solved the problem. I did it by installing the new asm addon.

Comment: Tugba, why did not you accept the answer?

Answer (score 1):

You need to perform an addon install of the ASM addon against your storefront. This will add the required javascript and styling

```
ant addoninstall -Daddonnames="assistedservicestorefront" -DaddonStorefront.<storefrontTemplateName>="Storefront1"
```

Comment: yes, I added it as a comment that I solved the problem in this way, thanks anyway.

Comment: I must have missed that :) glad you got it resolved